# How to print Xcode UIview names programatically in Swift 4

Tags: xcode, uiview, swift4

In XCode, you can create a view hierarchy.  The names of the views are generic -- *label*, *text*, *slider*, *view*, *stack view*, etc.  In the interface, you can rename these controls to something meaningful.  **How do you access this name from within the program in Swift 4?**  I'm  trying to debug an issue with parents, subviews, and zPosition and it would be very helpful to recursively display all the control names and their selected properties.

Comment: Create an `IBOutlet` and connect it to the view of interest, then set a breakpoint somewhere and examine its subviews. Also check out the [View Hierarchies debugger](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html)

Comment: Thx.  But I don't want to be limited to interactive debugging.  I want to be able to "print" the status of the hierarchy and upload for review later.